# imagettftext \\n line break puzzle

Tags: php, imagettftext

in PHP imagettftext, should I be able to make line breaks with "\n" in a string like this?

```
// The text to draw
$text = 'Something\nElse';
```

When I try this, the text outputted reads "Something\\nElse" with 2 back slashes before the n.

This does not result in a line-break.

Firstly, SHOULD a single slash n make a line break (\n)?
Secondly, How do i get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is a line break [only when the string is delimited with double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
echo 'Something\nElse';  // outputs Something\nElse
echo "Something\nElse";  // outputs Something
                         //         Else
```

Comment: You're kidding me! Thanks!  Right, that works for strings defined in the PHP directly,

but now I'm using GET to set the text by changing the URL, 

$quotes = $_GET["msg"];

URL image.php?msg=Something\nElse 

Results in \\n (two slashes before the n)

Do you know why this happens? "msg" is in double quotes so should it not work?